# Issue with ng-init scope variable on ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following input field with ng-init scope variable

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="formData.TEST" ng-init="formdata.TEST='{{ scopeVariable }}'" value="{{ scopeVariable }}" />
```

The `{{ scopeVariable }}` value get from controller:

```
$scope.scopeVariable = '123456';
```

When check the field value from the developer tools this looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="formData.TEST" ng-init="formdata.TEST='123456'" value="123456" />
```

But when submit the form with ng-submit I got the following object:

```
LOREM: 'IPSUM'
IPSUM: 'LOREM'
TEST: "{{ scopeVariable }}"
```

How can I init the model value correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-init` is already an expression, so you don't need to add the handlebars.

`ng-init="formdata.TEST = scopeVariable"` should be sufficient.

Also be careful of casing. `formData` and `formdata` are two different objects! Lastly the `value` attribute is unnecessary as you have `ng-model`. So I would write it as:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="formData.TEST" ng-init="formData.TEST = scopeVariable" />
```